# Using public and private ip at the same time on ubuntu(virtual box)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am using Virtual Box to run Ubuntu on Windows server machine because I am remotely working on this machine and needed ssh to control it.(I can not go to the place where the machine is located.)

When I installed Ubuntu on it, it could use a internet connection and downloaded update files. It used DHCP when I checked an interfaces file.

However, after I assigned static public IP on Ubuntu, it started not be able to connect to another sever, which has a private IP.

What I am intended to do is described below:

```
User(internet) <-> Ubuntu server(public IP) <-> MS SQL server(private IP)
```

These Ubuntu server and MS SQL server are installed in separated machines.

So I thought the Ubuntu needs another LAN card and also a private IP. I added a virtual LAN card with virtual box and assigned a private IP(192.168....)

```
Ubuntu
eth0: 54.121.23.45(just example)
eth1: 192.168.112.6
eth0 and eth1 are bridged to the same LAN card of the host machine.
```

But eth1 does not work and can not connect to the internet, even to the local network that uses the same IP range(same gateway??).

I checked it with this command:

```
ping -I eth1 (some ip addresses)
```

My question is this:

1. Is this the right way to hide a database server from the outside?
2. What is wrong with the "eth1"? Why can not it connect to the internet neither to local network?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It was because of physical connections to the different switching hubs.
I used a wire of the internet to connect to the local intranet.
So silly...